# Parsing XML - get node based on children

Tags: php, xml

I am struggeling to get the node based on the children. So I wan't to get the full person by id 4061106. I am using SimpleXMLElement, for now I did a foreach loop to display all persons but I cannot figure out how to get by a specific id. I do not even know where to start from.

```
<list>
        <person>
            <id>4061106</id>
            <name>Stefan</name>
            <country></country>
            <is_admin>0</is_admin>
            <lastCallbackTime></lastCallbackTime>

        </person>
        <person>
            <id>4082930</id>
            <name>Mike</name>
            <is_admin>0</is_admin>
            <lastCallbackTime></lastCallbackTime>

        </person>
</list>
```

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Xpath to find the  node with the correct value, and then jump back up to the parent  node.

```
$xml = '
  <list>
    <person>
      <id>4061106</id>
      <name>Stefan</name>
      <country></country>
      <is_admin>0</is_admin>
      <lastCallbackTime></lastCallbackTime>
    </person>
  </list>
';

$sxml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$person = $sxml->xpath('/list/person/id[.="4061106"]/parent::person')[0];

echo (string) $person->name; // Stefan
```

Comment: I use $oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($sXML); and I pass that into the simplexml_load_string and get an error parser error : Start tag expected, '<', the result is a XML its wrapped xml->list

Comment: You just need to pass a string of XML into simplexml_load_string. So $xml needs to be set to the string in your original post.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you're getting the XML, just pass it (as a string) straight into the simplexml_load_string line. You don't need to create any other SimpleXMLElement objects. I've edited the answer the clarity.

Comment: the list is also wrapped with <xml> </xml>

Comment: If you add an extra / at the start of the xpath() expression (e.g. //list), it will work at any level of nesting.